# Does schema normalization enhances query efficiency?

Tags: database

I am not getting whether normalization actually enhances the efficiency of query or not since  normalization improves update, delete and insert speed but data retrieval is expensive due to presence of many tables , so then what should be our conclusion ?

Comment: Normalisation is more about data integrity (by reducing redundancy) than it is about query efficiency. Sometimes non normalized tables are faster to query, but the updates are slower because multiple tables need to be updated, and since data is duplicated, it cannot be guaranteed to be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter how fast you get your data if the data is invalid.  Normalization helps to ensure that each fact is recorded only once, and it can help efficiency by eliminating redundant associations and reusing indexed columns.  Narrow tables can be more efficient since more related data fit into each physical page.  However, if your data access patterns are inefficient, normalization will cost you, but so will network latency, query parsing, planning, locking, logging, etc.